# Factory variable is undefined in controller

Tags: angularjs

I would like to get assistance on one subject. I have created AuthService for login process. After login, user is being redirected to homepage. Homepage has a controller named ApplicationController. This controller is watching AuthService for variable change. In this step, `AuthService.getUser()` returns undefined. I have searched the solution and applied all the recommended solutions, but still there is no change. Could anybody help me to understand the problem?

**LoginController.js**

```
app.controller('LoginController', ['$scope', '$window', 'AuthService', function ($scope, $window, AuthService) {
$scope.username = null;
$scope.password = null;
$scope.error = null;

$scope.login = function () {
    $scope.error = null;
    AuthService.login({ username: $scope.username, password: $scope.password },
        function success(data, status, headers, config) {

            // redirect to homepage, which has ApplicationController
            $window.location = "/";
        },
        function error(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.error = data.error_description;
        });
}
}]);
```

**AuthService.js**

```
app.factory('AuthService', function ($http) {
var authService = {};

var currentUser;

authService.login = function (credentials, successCallback, errorCallback) {
    $http({
        // do some $http config
    }).success(function (data, status) {
        var loggedInUser = {
            Username: data.Username,
            Name: data.Name,
            Surname: data.Surname,
            Email: data.Email,
            ID: data.ID,
            MobileNumber: data.MobileNumber,
            Role: data.Role
        };
        currentUser = loggedInUser; // here set the currentUser
        successCallback(data, status);
    }).error(function (data, status) {
        errorCallback(data, status);
    });
};

authService.isLoggedIn = function () {
    return currentUser != undefined ? true : false;
};
authService.getUser = function () {
    return currentUser;
};

return authService;
})
```

**ApplicationController.js**

```
app.controller('ApplicationController', function ($scope, $location, $window, AuthService) {
   $scope.currentUser;
   $scope.isAuthenticated;

   $scope.$watch(AuthService.isLoggedIn, function (isLoggedIn) {

   // here AuthService.getUser() returns undefined.   
   $scope.currentUser = AuthService.getUser(); 
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

ApplicationController should be watching the *return value* of `AuthService.isLoggedIn`, so:

```
$scope.$watch(function () {
    return AuthService.isLoggedIn();
}, function (isLoggedIn) {
```

not:

```
$scope.$watch(AuthService.isLoggedIn, function (isLoggedIn) {
```

Comment: $scope.$watch(AuthService.isLoggedIn, function (isLoggedIn) {  is still evaluating the result of isLoggedIn. So there is nothing wrong here. Even I changed the that part, getUser returns undefined.

Answer (score 0):

$scope.$watch accepts function as watch expression so you could return value of isLoggedIn

```
app.controller('ApplicationController', function ($scope, $location, $window, AuthService) {
    $scope.currentUser;
    $scope.isAuthenticated;

    $scope.$watch(function () {return AuthService.isLoggedIn();}, function (isLoggedIn) {

    // here AuthService.getUser() returns undefined.   
    $scope.currentUser = AuthService.getUser(); 
    });
});
```